# How to execute a calculation in python and capture the output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, vim, capture

How can I execute a calculation in python (2.7) and capture the output in the variable 'results'?

**Input:**

```
let calculation = '(3*15)/5'
let formatting  = '\\%2d'
let grouping = '0'

exe "python -c \"import math, locale; locale.format(formatting, calculation, grouping)\""
```

and capture the output in a variable `results`

**Output:**

results = '9'

ps:
Is there also a possibility in python to wrap the first part of my calculation, something like the eval() function in vim?
p.e.

```
  let command = 'python -c \"import math, locale\"'
  exe "eval(command); locale.format(formatting, calculation, grouping)"
```

Comment: Have you considered using the python command instead of an external python interpreter? (Assuming vim has been compiled with python support)

Comment: The python command? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3):

Hmm… `:let foo = (3*15)/15`.

Anyway, you can capture the output of an external command with `:let foo = system('mycommand')`:

```
:let foo = system("python -c 'print (15*3)/5'")
```

It's up to you to put the string together.

Comment: Thank you romainl. I tried this without success: `let foo = system("python -c \"str.format('\%2d', ((15*3)/5))\"") | echo foo` What's wrong with it? Your solution gives also an error on my system: E484: Can't open file C:\users\username\AppData\temp\VIo9EBD.tmp

Comment: what would be the answer of my question using `system()`? After trying and trying, I can't make it work.

Comment: Found it out.. This works `let calcol = "(15*3)/5" let command = "python -c \"import math,locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ''); print(locale.format('\%.2f',".calcol.",1))\"" let results = system (command)`, but it is very very slow if you do many calcolations on different lines :(

Answer (score 1):

I ever wrote a script to do number calculation in vim. It supports three expression evaluation engines: `GNU bc, vimscript and python`.

It is called `HowMuch` : https://github.com/sk1418/HowMuch

For the python part, you could check here:

https://github.com/sk1418/HowMuch/blob/master/autoload/HowMuch.vim#L285

hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Kent, Nice plugin. I will keep it. What I miss is the indication from which country you are. Decimals are indicated with the comma in western Europe. Thousands with the dot.

Comment: Kent, with your plugin in my mind, I'm sure you know all about calculations and python. What would be your answer on my question using system() or whatever python code? Can you please add it as a new answer?